# Getting all records in a set using the Sickle package

Tags: python, records, oai

How can I access all the records in each set using Sickle?

I can access sets like this, but I don't know how to go from here and download each record from every set:

```
from sickle import Sickle

sickle = Sickle('http://www.duo.uio.no/oai/request')
    sets = sickle.ListSets()
    for s in sets:
        print s
```

The print prints out every set like this:

```
<set xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><setSpec>com_10852_1</setSpec><setName>Det matematisk-naturvitenskapelige fakultet</setName></set>
```

I can also iterate through the sets to go deeper:

```
for s in sets:
    for rec in sets:
        print rec
```

This prints all the sub-sets, so it's probably from here I can get access to the individual records, but the API is hard to understand, and I have not be able to access the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to read the short and sweet [Tutorial](https://sickle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html).

For harvesting an entire OAI-PMH repository, you do not need to iterate over sets. Here is the complete code:

```
from sickle import Sickle

sickle = Sickle('http://www.duo.uio.no/oai/request')
recs = sickle.ListRecords(metadataPrefix="oai_dc")
for r in recs:
    print r
```

If for some reason you really wish to harvest records set by set, you can certainly do so. Here is the complete code again:

```
from sickle import Sickle

sickle = Sickle('http://www.duo.uio.no/oai/request')
sets = sickle.ListSets()
for s in sets:
    recs = sickle.ListRecords(metadataPrefix="oai_dc", set=s.setSpec)
    for r in recs:
        print r
```